# Error en la web con: "bad URI or cross-site access not allowed source: "

Tags: html, css

Tengo este error:

> downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "font-test"
>   style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): bad URI or
>   cross-site access not allowed source:
>   http://subdominio.dominio.net/public/fonts/font-test.ttf

La estructura de carpetas es esta:

```
/public
   /css
      /fonts.css
   /fonts
      /font-test.ttf
```

¿Como puedo habilitar el `cross-site access` desde `php` ya que no dispongo de acceso al archivo conf del servidor?

**EDITADO**

He probado a poner: `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` como me indicaba: [carmen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/76226/45237). Pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: Estás probando en Chrome?

Comment: En firefox @ErlantzCalvo

Comment: y estás probando con algún servidor? de ser así que tipo de servidor es?

Comment: Es un servidor linux de un proveedor externo @ErlantzCalvo

Comment: No te lo voy a poner en respuesta porque no sé si te voy a resolver algo, pero en todos los sitios que he visto con los mismos problemas lo han resuelto [así](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025681/8025091). básicamente es como ha dicho Carmen, pero poniéndolo en el servidor.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que la url es correcta, en php:

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

O en el servidor si tienes acceso:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: No me funciona con `php` y las urls son correctas

Comment: Otra opción posible es que tu página sea https y la fuente http, en este caso debería ser también https para mantener la integridad. Si no es posible que necesites editar el virtual host del servidor.